# Windows 10 Home resets some registry settings on reboot

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, services

For firewall purposes I made a copy of `svchost.exe` called `mysvchost.exe` and made some services run on `mysvchost.exe` by editing their `ImagePath` in the registry (under `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services`). However, on reboot I noticed that the settings have reverted back to the old `svchost.exe`. How do I make the changed `ImagePath` stick through the reboot?

Comment: I expect (not totally certain) that this program is being replaced by the valid copy in WinSXS.  I don't think you can solve your problem this way. If you could, any virus writer could do the same thing and screw up your system (and everyone else's)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I am replacing `svchost.exe` in `System32` by its exact copy (and not even replacing, just keeping the copy under the name `mysvchost` alongside it). I don't see svchost in WinSXS. Regarding the viruses, Windows can just check that `mysvchost` has exactly the same hash as the original svchost and is digitally signed by Microsoft.

Comment: I found a bunch of svchost.exe files in WinSXS (by processor model). I am not sure how else Windows would have replaced it (and it apparently did)

Comment: Ok, yes, you're right, there are svchost files in WinSXS. But it doesn't have anything to do with my question. My svchost wasn't replaced because I never deleted it in the first place. It's still sitting where it's always been, in `system32`. Also my copy of it, `mysvchost.exe` is still there as well, not deleted by Windows Defender or whatever. The only thing I changed was `ImagePath` in the registry for some services and those registry edits got reverted by Windows.